# Integrate java console in a GUI

Tags: java, eclipse, console, windowbuilder

i've a GUI (done with eclipse and windowbuilder), i would like to open (in a jframe or in a new window near from my GUI) a console which displays my System.out.println and my printstacktrace (inter alia).

How can i do that?
Do i really have to develop a console?

(I don't want to be sure that the user launched my jar from his cmd.exe)

Answer (score 3):

Using `System.setOut` and `System.setErr`, you can re-direct console output to `PrintStream`s of your choice. So you can send all output to a text area inside your frame.

Answer (score 2):

There is a [SourceForge project](http://sourceforge.net/p/java42developmentconsole/svn/HEAD/tree/) that will pop a console window for displaying multiple object types.

From the project:

Description

The Java42 Development Console is a replacement for Java's System class. This is a development tool intended to be used during application development but can also be packaged and shipped with your product.

Example usage:

```
import java42.lang.System;

System.getManager().initialize(owner); // Owner is your app's JFrame

// All System.out.xxx methods are routed to the console.

// Print text:
System.out.println("Hello Console"); 

// Print components:
System.out.println(new JButton("Hello Console")); 

// Print images:
System.out.println(ImageIO.read(imageStream));
```

[image]